# Common task run once in GruntJS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I would like to have a common task in GruntJS, which wouldn't be run for second time if already run by different task in the same session.

For example, I have tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask("make_win", ["prepare_dist", "copy_win", "compress_win"]);
grunt.registerTask("make_linux", ["prepare_dist", "copy_linux", "compress_linux"]);
grunt.registerTask("make", ["make_win", "make_linux"]);
```

How it works right now:

- when make is invoked, following tasks are run: **prepare_dist**, copy_win, compress_win,  **prepare_dist**, copy_linux, compress_linux (so, prepare_dist is run twice, but it's not necessary since the dist (common base) is already prepared);

What I want to achieve:

- when make_win is invoked, following tasks should be run: **prepare_dist**, copy_win, etc;
- when make_linux is invoked, following tasks should be run: **prepare_dist**, copy_linux, etc;
- when make is invoked, following tasks should be run: **prepare_dist**, copy_win, compress_win, copy_linux, compress_linux (so, prepare_dist is skipped, because already run);

Comment: So, no straight answer. I assume that grunt doesn't support that. Weird, seems like an easy and "common" requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a callback as a task, in the task check if `run` true or not:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'A sample task that runs once.', function() {
  if (!run) {
    grunt.task.run('bar');
    run = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: A lot of work for a such common requirement (make has it out of the box :) If no one proposes a better solution I gonna accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I see what you want, and I think it's a neat idea, but I don't think there is anything in Grunt set up to do this. Unfortunately, I think the only way to do this is to split out the tasks a bit more:

```
grunt.registerTask("make_win_specific", ["copy_win", "compress_win"]);
grunt.registerTask("make_linux_specific", ["copy_linux", "compress_linux"]);

grunt.registerTask("make_win", ["prepare_dist", "make_win_specific"]);
grunt.registerTask("make_linux", ["prepare_dist", "make_linux_specific"]);

grunt.registerTask("make", ["prepare_dist", "make_win_specific", "make_linux_specific"]);
```